# Can we call a soap service with the query parameter appended to it?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
  http://localhost:8280/services/sampleService?wsdl
```

I have a soap service can i append a query parameter to it and make a call without the soap action ?.

The consumer is saying he will not send any soap action he will invoke the service like below i'm not sure how it is possible in soap can some one give a clear idea about it.

`http://localhost:8280/services/sampleService?wsdl&op=CreateOrder`